# How to get Spotify current playing song in Python (Windows)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, spotify

I want to show the current playing song in Spotify on a 16x2 LCD.
I was thinking of connecting the LCD with my Arduino and then making a Python script that sends the current playing song of Spotify to the Arduino.

To get to the point, I'm looking for a way to get Spotify's current playing song in Python. (I'm using Windows 8.) I found some ways like dbus, but they were either for Linux or for Mac.

Thanks in advance! (And sorry for bad English grammar.)

Comment: I haven't used it, but you might find [pytify](https://github.com/bjarneo/Pytify) helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately it's Mac and Linux only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I encountered the same issue, so I wrote a library to solve this issue. The library can be found at github: https://github.com/XanderMJ/spotilib. Keep in mind that this is still work in progress.

Just copy the file and place it in your Python/Lib directory.

```
import spotilib
spotilib.artist() #returns the artist of the current playing song
spotilib.song() #returns the song title of the current playing song
```

spotilib.artist() returns only the first artist. I started working on an other library *spotimeta.py* to solve this issue. However, this is not working at 100% yet.

```
import spotimeta
spotimeta.artists() #returns a list of all the collaborating artists of the track
```

If an error occurs, *spotimeta.artists()* will return only the first artist (found with *spotilib.artist()*)

Hope this will help you (if still needed)!

Comment: Thanks, awesome you still take the effort to answer this question, even through it's >1 year old. I'm gonna look at it soon. If I can help you with the development of the module, please let me know. (Although I'm not 100% if I'm able to help you, but I'll at least try.)

Comment: En je zit ook op de TU Delft, dat is ook awesome haha. Ik ga zelf nu beginnen aan het tweede jaar bachelor electrical engineering. Welk jaar civiel doe jij? / You're studying at TU Delft too, that's awesome. I gonna start my second year of the bachelor electrical engineering. In which year of civil engineering are you?

Comment: @Kevin Always nice to meet a fellow student! At the moment i'm starting my 4th year of civil engineering (still batchelor tho). || Hoe zou ik in contact kunnen komen met jou?

Comment: contact-at-kevinvandertoorn-dot-nl (met @ i.p.v. -at- en een punt i.p.v. -dot-). Ik moet ook nog een paar vakken van vorig jaar opnieuw doen haha. (Kwantum mechanica is lastig. :P)

Comment: whoops... het moet email -at- kevinvandertoorn -dot- nl zijn, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would probably be to scrobble the currently playing tracks from the Spotify client to a last.fm account and then use python to get it from there.

Last.fm allows you to get scrobbled tracks via their api with [user.getRecentTracks](http://www.last.fm/api/show/user.getRecentTracks) which provides the `nowplaying="true"` attribute if a song is playing. It also provides some other useful things you may want for an external display like a link to the album art and last.fm page for the song.

Here's a quick example that takes a username and api key as cmd line arguments and fetches what is currently playing for that user using the requests library.

```
from time import sleep
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint
import sys    

def get_playing():
    base_url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user='
    user = sys.argv[1]
    key = sys.argv[2]
    r = requests.get(base_url+user+'&api_key='+key+'&format=json')
    data = json.loads(r.text)
    latest_track = data['recenttracks']['track'][0]
    try:
        if latest_track['@attr']['nowplaying'] == 'true':
            artist = latest_track['artist']['#text']
            song = latest_track['name']
            album = latest_track['album']['#text']
            print "\nNow Playing: {0} - {1}, from the album {2}.\n".format(artist, song, album)
    except KeyError:
        print '\nNothing playing...\n'    

def main():
    if len(sys.argv)<3:
        print "\nError: Please provide a username and api key in the format of: 'scrobble.py username api_key\n"
    else:
        get_playing()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In a quick test it does seem to take a minute or so to realize the track is no longer playing after pausing or exiting the Spotify client however.

Comment: To whomever downvoted this without commenting: that's kind of rude, and against the spirit of SO guidelines.

Comment: This is a good answer, but could be improved it explained benefits: this works with more than just Spotify, and is immune to breakage by changes to the Spotify client (unless they removed Scrobble support someday). Also, explaining or linking what Scrobble "is", for most folks. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

Is there more than one pytify ?
This worked for me until today:
https://code.google.com/p/pytify/

Spotify has been updated, now song is not shown in windows title anymore.

They will bring the "feature" back:
https://community.spotify.com/t5/ideas/v2/ideapage/blog-id/ideaexchange/article-id/73238/page/2#comments

Answer (score -3):

while True:
print("Welcome to the project, " + user_name['display_name'])

```
print("0 - Exit the console")

print("1 - Search for a Song")

user_input = int(input("Enter Your Choice: "))

if user_input == 1:
    search_song = input("Enter the song name: ")

    results = spotifyObject.search(search_song, 1, 0, "track")
    songs_dict = results['tracks']
    song_items = songs_dict['items']
    song = song_items[0]['external_urls']['spotify']
    webbrowser.open(song)
    print('Song has opened in your browser.')
elif user_input == 0:

    print("Good Bye, Have a great day!")
    break
else:
    print("Please enter valid user-input.")
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question to show the current playing song in Spotify.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).