# How to get the currently played media title on windows using python?

Tags: python, windows, audio-player

[How do I get this title using python?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPtFQ.png)

I haven't tried anything yet since I do not know which library should I use and how.

Comment: OP wants to know what library can be used to get that name, I am not sure there is nothing they can show to try if they cant get started

Comment: Well @R.Barzell, python_user pretty much summed it up, I do not know how to start solving this problem and I did not find any thread that addresses it online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this StackOverflow Question - since your picture as music played by spotify, this question might help you.

[How to get Spotify current playing song in Python (Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062319/how-to-get-spotify-current-playing-song-in-python-windows)

They are referring to this Library: https://github.com/XanderMJ/spotilib

If you wanna directly control spotify via Python you might also have a look at this library: https://pypi.org/project/pyspotify/

For interaction with the Spotify Web Api, this might also be helpful: https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/

Comment: Thank you philipp for this repo, but I think that this is outdated, Spotify's window title is no longer "SpotifyMainWindow", it is now the name of the current song so the spotilib is unable to find it and throws an error.